# Changing where "posted on" text is located in TwentyEleven?

Tags: theme-twenty-eleven

In TwentyEleven the "posted on" text is well above the title. I want it to replace the "posted in category" text.

Is there a php file that populates the page where I can just edit where this stuff pops out? I checked my `pages.php` file but I couldn't seem to figure out what to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the twentyeleven theme which it looks like you are, there is a function called twentyeleven_posted_on(), on line 24 within your content.php  file. If you want to move the posted on below then move this piece of code ->

```
<?php if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) : ?>
        <div class="entry-meta">
            <?php twentyeleven_posted_on(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Down to the footer section, look at line 55 or do a search on your IDE for "posted in". You'll see some code like the following ->

```
<?php printf( __( '<span class="%1$s">Posted in</span> %2$s', 'twentyeleven' ), 'entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-cat-links', $categories_list ); ?>
```

Either comment out this code or remove it and replace it with the above code.

Just so you know, when you looked at your page.php file you will notice a function call to ->

```
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
```

This is calling the content-page.php file. Even within this you won't find the changes you want to make because it appears your blog page is calling index.php. Within index.php this is calling the following ->

```
<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
```

This will load the content.php file with your posted on and posted in code e.t.c.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks thirdOctet, that does help. I have one last question. I'm using a Child Theme for twentyeleven, is there any way to make these changes to the Child Theme only?

Comment: Hey Luke, is the child theme a separate directory with all the files such as content.php, content-single.php, functions.php e.t.c

Comment: Yep, I think I got it though. I just copied content.php into my child theme folder. :) Previously it was very barebones.

Comment: no worries luke glad you got it fixed

Comment: If you look, you'll noticed that the theme is handling everything properly now. Thanks so much for the help. :)

Comment: nice nice, saw the changes =) . would you be able to mark your question as answered?